# JUnit 4.9 does not support assumption failure messages

Tags: junit4, junit5

Why junit5 (actually > v4.9) does not support descriptions in Assumption class methods? It was very useful feature for fast debug. What is an idea of this removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is an idea of this removal?

This functionality has *not* been removed.

On the contrary, it never existed in JUnit 4.9. Rather, it was not introduced until JUnit 4.11, and it has remained in place ever since then.

If it appears that those methods have been removed, the only viable explanation is that you downgraded your JUnit 4.x version to something prior to JUnit 4.11.

Regarding JUnit 5: for each method in `Assumptions`, there are two variants that accept messages (what you call *descriptions*). The messages are always the last argument in JUnit Jupiter. For example, the `assumeTrue()` method has the following two variants that accept a `String` or a `Supplier<String>`.

- `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue(boolean, String)`
- `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue(boolean, Supplier<String>)`

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. But I meant org.junit.Assume class at my post (sorry, that was not too clear), and this class' accept messages has been changed.

Comment: Actually I know nothing about JUnit Jupiter, is it preferrable to use?

Comment: If you meant `org.junit.Assume`, then you posted to the wrong tag. The `junit5` tag is for JUnit 5 and not for JUnit 4.

Comment: In any case, the message support was never removed from JUnit 4's assumptions either. Rather, they were added in 4.11 and have been in place ever since. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: _JUnit Jupiter_ is the new programming model in JUnit 5.0. JUnit 5.0 M2 was just released last week. So there is no "final" 5.0 release yet, but we certainly encourage people to try out the milestones and provide feedback! ;)

Comment: BTW they did not added AssertThat methods and matchers to org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions and made some strange things with assumptions, but that's ok, let's wait for release.

Comment: If by _they_ you mean _me_, then yes... that's correct. I can partially take the credit/blame for that. And if by _strange_ you're referring to the support for lambda expressions, then... that's also correct. ;)

Comment: If my answer suffices for your needs, please "accept" the answer. Thanks!

Comment: For details on the omission of `assertThat` in JUnit 5, please see this issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/428

Comment: Nochmals vielen Dank!